# ImportError: cannot import name 'encode' , 'batch_gen' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.5, importerror

Hi I'm unable to import batch_gen, encode from Data library.

```
from data import batch_gen, encode
```

Error :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'batch_gen'

ImportError: cannot import name 'encode'
```

Python version :

```
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: I've never used this `data` library before. Are you sure it contains the imports you are looking for?

Comment: What is the `data` library?

Comment: yes, I'm working on building seq2seq model using Keras(with tensorflow backend) and this library is being used.

Comment: @Anagha Maybe add some relevant context and tags to this post then

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
from data import batch_gen, encode
```

Instead add these two functions

```
def encode(X,seq_len, vocab_size):
x = np.zeros((len(X),seq_len, vocab_size), dtype=np.float32)
for ind,batch in enumerate(X):
    for j, elem in enumerate(batch):
        x[ind, j, elem] = 1
return x

def batch_gen(batch_size=32, seq_len=10, max_no=100):
# Randomly generate a batch of integer sequences (X) and its sorted
# counterpart (Y)
x = np.zeros((batch_size, seq_len, max_no), dtype=np.float32)
y = np.zeros((batch_size, seq_len, max_no), dtype=np.float32)

while True:
# Generates a batch of input
    X = np.random.randint(max_no, size=(batch_size, seq_len))

    Y = np.sort(X, axis=1)

    for ind,batch in enumerate(X):
        for j, elem in enumerate(batch):
            x[ind, j, elem] = 1

    for ind,batch in enumerate(Y):
        for j, elem in enumerate(batch):
            y[ind, j, elem] = 1

    yield x, y
    x.fill(0.0)
    y.fill(0.0)
```